# WSO2 ESB 4.8.0 Proxy service transcoding iso to utf-8

Tags: encoding, proxy, apache-synapse, wso2-esb

Context:
I use wso2esb 4.8.0.
I have proxy service:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
       name="eProxy"
       transports="https"
       statistics="disable"
       trace="disable"
       startOnLoad="true">
   <target>
      <inSequence>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>         
      </outSequence>
      <endpoint>
         <address uri="http://10.24.74.53:8088/xxxService?WSDL"/>
      </endpoint>
   </target>
   <publishWSDL uri="file://wso2esb-4.8.0/repository/mcc/resources/xxx.wsdl"/>
   <description/>
</proxy>
```

Problem:
xxxService response is encoding in iso-8859 and I want to transform this response to utf-8

My first approch:
I use xslt mediator :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <result>
            <xsl:value-of select="." />
        </result>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

but I have error

```
ERROR NativeWorkerPool uncaught exception java.lang.stackoverflowerror com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanName(XMLEntityScanner.java:726)
```

My second approch:
I set property in out Sequence:

```
<property name='CHARACTER_SET_ENCODING' scope='Axis2' value='UTF-8'/>
```

but I have error

```
 ERROR NativeWorkerPool uncaught exception java.lang.stackoverflowerror com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLEntityScanner.scanName(XMLEntityScanner.java:726)
```

My last approch:
I write custom mediator but I dont know how chang SoapEnvelope or SoapBody encoding

thinks for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

To change encoding and content type, look at `ContentType` and `messageType` properties : http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB480/Generic+Properties

Sample value : `text/xml; charset=ISO-8859-1`

Comment: thinks you for your response. but contentType et messageType just concern incoming request.

with my second approch : the content-type change but soapbody isn't convert to utf-8.